# Как установить пакет wxPython 2.8 для Mandriva ?

Tags: wxpython, linux

Мне для Python нужно в Mandriva 2005 (дада, именно под эту версию) установить wxPython версии 2.8.

Для ubuntu это делалось так

```
apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8
```

Я в ubuntu-то новичок, а в Mandriva тем более. Как правильно это сделать? Какие могут быть проблемы (особенно из-за этого что версия старая, почти 6-7 летней давности)? rpm я скачал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
urpmi python-wxgtk2.8
```

или раз вы скачали rpm-пакет, установить его командой

```
rpm -Uvh имя пакета
```

Comment: Да так не получается. Я уже из исходников пытаюсь его собрать. Но... теперь не могу установить libgtk2.0-dev. Делаю для wxPython ./configure и получаю большое сообщение: The development files for GTK+ were not found. For GTK+ 2, please
ensure that pkg-config is in the path and that gtk+-2.0.pc is
installed. For GTK+ 1.2 please check that gtk-config is in the path,
and that the version is 1.2.3 or above. Also check that the
libraries returned by 'pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs' or 'gtk-config
--libs' are in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or equivalent.